# Sitecore Analytics Channel Detection

Tags: xdb, mongodb, marketing-definitions

Sitecore has a bunch of Channels defined in `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Channel`.The config `Sitecore.Analytics.Channel` specify the different channels that are assigned for different scenarios.

In the `Interactions` collection in MongoDB, the `ReferringSite` is the name of actual site. So the value of the ChannelId should be the item id of `Direct` channel.
Instead it is `NUUID("44dd9ff5-44b2-4c59-8df8-849e400f4b6b")` which is the item id of `Other referrals`.

After digging around, the code responsible for assigning the ChannelId is `Sitecore.Analytics.OmniChannel.Pipelines.DetermineInteractionChannel.ReferringSite`.

The code checks if `Tracker.Dictionaries.ReferringSites` contains the current site to know which channelId to assign to it.
The issue is that `Tracker.Dictionaries.ReferringSites` does not contain my site so it falls back to `Other referrals`.

Is there a way to populate `Tracker.Dictionaries.ReferringSites` with my site details? If so, how would I do this?

Sitecore Version is 8.2 Update 1.